# getDeclaredFields with actual runtime type, for Unsafe.objectFieldOffset(f)

Tags: java, class, serialization, reflection

getDeclaredFields[0].getType() is returning only the compile time class info. I have following code, where `java.lang.reflect.Field`'s type is expected with actual type. This field is passed to **Unsafe.objectFieldOffset(f)**

```
public class Wrapper {
     public Object field1;
      //getters and setters for field1 and constructor
}
class SomeClass {

}
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
wrapper.field1 = new SomeClass();
System.out.println(wrapper.getClass().getDeclaredFields[0].getType());
```

Even though object is available with wrapper.field1.getClass(), `Unsafe.objectFieldOffset(f)` requires Field instance so  `wrapper.getClass().getDeclaredFields[0].getType()` needs to return actual type which SomeClass instead of Object. Is there anyway I can override that behaviour ?

To rephrase,  Is there anyway to use ***`Unsafe.objectFieldOffset(f)`*** with Runtime type info?

Comment: The obvious question is: why do you need the object field offset in the first place. Secondly, you completely misunderstood how that method works, you just pass it the `Field` object belonging to `field1` (`long l = Unsafe.objectFieldOffset(wrapper.getClass().getDeclaredFields()[0]);`) and you're done with it, there is no need to get the runtime type of the object (and indeed it would make no sense either).

Comment: And personally I'd try to avoid using the `Unsafe` class altogether, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this will not be possible. `getDeclaredFields()` will do exactly that - return fields with compile-time information. You will have to retrieve the runtime type using `field1.getClass()`.

Edit: You may also indirectly retrieve the class, using `wrapper.getType().getDeclaredFields[0].get(wrapper).getClass();`

Comment: See my edit - you can use that line to indirectly get the object's class.

Comment: If you have no chance to declare field1 as another type, you won't have a chance at achieving what you want, sorry. I guess you couldn't use a "fake" `Field` instance either, since the serialization library will probably use it to retrieve the object itself (via `Field.get()`).

Comment: It's for Unsafe.objectFieldOffset(f)